# How to delete existing graph and plot a new graph?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In my program, I am doing a least squared optimization problem, i.e. `\sum_{i} (y_{i}-y_{i}^{market})^2`. At the same time, I want to plot the modeled `y_{i}` against the `y_{i}^{market}`. To program it which suit my needs, I define `OutputFcn` during my optimization and write the code as follow: (Suppose `x` represent the `x-coord`

```
figure()
hold on
plot(x,[y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}]);
plot(x,[y_{1}^{market},y_{2}^{market},...,y_{n}^{market}]);
```

When I run the program, I can draw a new calculated curves on the same plot. Unfortunately, the final plot is difficult to view it. In order to make it to be visible to read, I want to delete the curve (calculated values) obtained in the previous iteration and plot the new curve (calculated values) in the new iteration on the existing plot. What should I do to the current code to fulfill my needs?

Comment: This does not look like regular matlab syntax. Are you using some kind of special toolbox ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
hold on
for iterations
    clf
    % PLOT STUFF
    drawnow
    pause(0.1)
end
```

- `clf` clears the figure
- `drawnow` forces drawing on screen
- `pause` stops execution for a bit so you have time to see it.